# Can I display the results of a web scraper on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I made a web scraper script with node.js but my host does not allow to use the exec() function, so I can not run this script from a webpage to print the results for the person who is visiting the webpage and hits the button which should launch the script.

Is there any other way, I could print the results to the visitor?

I used cheerio and request for the web scraping.

Comment: well, if you can't execute the node.js app, you're pretty much out of luck as far as using node.js to solve this problem, right? Or am i misinterpreting the problem.

Comment: Can I do this without having to reach back to the server? For example from a javascript code directly from the page?

Comment: No, unless the website you are scraping is allowing CORS from your origin or all origins.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? I'm not sure how `exec()` fits in as it's a regex function. Maybe you're looking for `eval()`?

Comment: I have a VPS with a node.js script on it. I would like to do the following: If a user presses a specific button on my website, this button launches the script on my server, which for example collects the best prices for various webshops, then prints it back to the html page.

Comment: So you can run the Node script but not `exec()` in the Node script? Or you can't run node at all? If you can run Node, what are you using `exec()` for anyways?

Comment: I can run the node script directly on the server via SSH. But I would like to invoke this script from a webpage.